# count the number of disks that have moved in Towers of hanoi Lisp

Tags: recursion, lisp

I want to count the number of moves of the diskc. but Instead As a result I get something else.

```
(setq x 0)

(defun towersOfHanoi (n from to help)
  (if (> n 0)
   ;progn evaluates multiple forms and returns the result from the last one.*/
   (progn
     (towersOfHanoi (- n 1) from help to)
     (format t "~d ----> ~d~%" from to)
     (towersOfHanoi (- n 1) help to from)
     (+ 1 x)
     )  

    ))



;(towersOfHanoi 3 'A 'B 'C)
```

When I run it I get

```
(towersOfHanoi 3 'A 'B 'C)
A ----> B
A ----> C
B ----> C
A ----> B
C ----> A
C ----> B
A ----> B
1
```

why it is one instead of 7, I guess with every recursive call is resetting the value of x to 0 but, how can I get the number of moves of the disks. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In lisp `if` takes at most three arguments; the condition, the form to evaluate when the condition is true, and the form to evaluate if it is false.

Se http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_if.htm for details.

In order to evaluate more than one form in a branch, you can use `progn` that evaluates multiple forms and returns the result from the last one.

Also, `princ` expects just one argument to be printed. In order to print several things at once, you may use `format`

In your case (remark also the placement of the parentheses):

```
(defun towersOfHanoi (n from to help)
 (if (> n 0)
   (progn
     (towersOfHanoi (1- n) from to help)
     (format t "~d ----> ~d~%" from to)
     (towersOfHanoi (1- n) help to from))))
```

Having no false branch, you may also use `when` that can evaluate more than one form:

```
(defun towersOfHanoi (n from to help)
  (when (> n 0)
    (towersOfHanoi (1- n) from to help)
    (format t "~d ----> ~d~%" from to)
    (towersOfHanoi (1- n) help to from)))
```

In order to count the moves, you can use a local counting variable (introduced with `let`), and an inner working function (introduced with `labels`) that updates this variable:

```
(defun towers-of-hanoi (n &optional (from 1) (to 2) (help 3))
  (let ((counter 0))                                          ; local variable
    (labels ((towers-of-hanoi-core (n from to help)           ; local function
               (when (> n 0)
                 (towers-of-hanoi-core (1- n) from to help)
                 (incf counter)                        
                 (format t "~d ----> ~d~%" from to)
                 (towers-of-hanoi-core (1- n) help to from))))
      (towers-of-hanoi-core n from to help))                  ; leave work to inner function
    (format t "Moves: ~d ~%" counter)))
```

Here,  from, to, and help is made optional as well, defaulting to 1, 2, and 3.

Again: The details are found in the Hyperspec: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/

Comment: You should change `n-1` to `(- n 1)`.

Comment: Thanks I have been trying to put a counter to count the number of times the disks are being moved but is not working. I think I need to declare a global variable to count it. Othervise everytime the recursion is called is going to set the variable to the initial value. Can you help with that

Comment: You have to declare a variable whose scope includes the definition of your function, but it does not have to be global.  Se my updated answer in which a local variable and a locally defined function is used.